# Conditional date filter

Tags: pandas

I am trying to split a series of timestamps into groups:

Define variables:

```
Very old = Date < '20190101'
Current = Today's date as %Y-%m (Year-Month)
```

Conditions

```
1. timestamp < very old
2. Very old < timestamp < current
3. timestamp = current
4. timestamp > current
```

Series that had been split from original DataFrame:

```
timestamp_dict = \
{0: Timestamp('2019-05-01 00:00:00'),
 1: Timestamp('2019-05-01 00:00:00'),
 2: Timestamp('2018-12-01 00:00:00'),
 3: Timestamp('2019-05-01 00:00:00'),
 4: Timestamp('2019-05-01 00:00:00'),
 5: Timestamp('2019-05-01 00:00:00'),
 6: Timestamp('2019-04-01 00:00:00'),
 7: Timestamp('2019-08-01 00:00:00')}
```

The datetimes are stored as datetime64[ns].
I have a feeling converting current timestamp to str is wrong, however, I am not sure how to extract the current timestamp as format `%Y-%m`.

I have an idea on accessing current date as month, year integers and then concatenating but then I would probably run into zero padding issues:

```
_month = dt.datetime.today().month
_year = dt.datetime.today().year

# Would run into zero padding for months 1-9:
current = str(_year) + str(_month)
```

Here, I try to generate a new DataFrame column using np.select and specifying my required conditions.

```
import datetime as dt

current = dt.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m')
veryold = '20190101'

conditions = [
    df.Delivery < veryold,
    (df.Delivery >= veryold | (df.Delivery < current),
    df.Delivery == current,
    df.Delivery > current
]

outcome = [
    'Very old',
    'Old',
    'Current',
    'Future'
]

df['New'] = np.select(conditions, outcome)

df.New
```

My expected output is to have an additional column of labeled outcomes in my DataFrame.

Comment: `veryold` is not  `2019-01` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is create month periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) for possible compare by `YYYY-MM`:

```
current = pd.Timestamp(pd.datetime.today()).to_period('M')
veryold = pd.Timestamp('20190101')

conditions = [
    df.Delivery < veryold,
    (df.Delivery >= veryold) | (df.Delivery.dt.to_period('M') < current),
    df.Delivery.dt.to_period('M') == current,
    df.Delivery.dt.to_period('M') > current]

outcome = [
    'Very old',
    'Old',
    'Current',
    'Future'
]

df = pd.Series(pd.Timestamp_dict).to_frame('Delivery')
df['New'] = np.select(conditions, outcome)
print(df)
    Delivery       New
0 2019-05-01       Old
1 2019-05-01       Old
2 2018-12-01  Very old
3 2019-05-01       Old
4 2019-05-01       Old
5 2019-05-01       Old
6 2019-04-01       Old
7 2019-08-01       Old
```

Comment: Idea given worked great, I have much to learn from you @jezrael thanks for helping out